# Вывод XML файла в Laravel из Storage

Tags: php, laravel, xml

Всех приветствую. Начинаю изучаться тему XML и SOAP протокола, подскажите как вывести мой XML файл из Storage.

```
return response(self::FILE)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для начала выведите dd(self::FILE) - возможно у вас там не xml, а ссылка на файл... А отправлять нужно именно содержимое.

Если файл храниться на сервере, то попробуйте следующим образом:

```
return response(file_get_contents(storage_path('filename.xml')), 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'
]);
```